# how to send data to server with both post and get methods in html?

Tags: php, html, forms, post, get

hope everything is great for you.
I've been developing a website and for user's registration part, I have a database. In the database, beside users' personal info, there is a column called "inviter". I don't ask users to fill that field when they are signing up. In the user profile page I have placed a section which generates a link like this : `<localhost/theme/signup.php?inviter=user>` this is the code of the section :

```
<?php
define( 'DB_SERVER', 'localhost' );
define( 'DB_USERNAME', 'root' );
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', '' );
define( 'DB_DATABASE', 'test' );
$db = mysqli_connect( DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE );
session_start();
if ( count( $_SESSION ) > 0 ) {
    $user = $_SESSION['logged_user'];
    $base = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
    $result = $base . '/signup.php?q=inviter=' . $user;
    echo($result);
}
?>
```

When a new user clicks on this link, and goes to sign up page, he has a inviter value sent by get method (I MEAN IN THE URL). But unfortunately this doesn't work for me. I mean when I want to use the "inviter" value and add it to database beside user's personal info, there is no index "inviter" in `$_GET` !

Can you please help me. BTW my for signing up I use a form with "method" value set to "post".

Answer (score 1):

Because URL parameter is invalid:

```
$result = $base . '/signup.php?q=inviter=' . $user;
$result = $base . '/signup.php?inviter=' . $user;
                               ^ Remove 'q='
```

Comment: @user3559500 This is not related to the typography, and if the URL format is wrong, PHP error reporting cannot detect it.